# Xpath: Igonore nodes with certain innertext

Tags: xpath

how can you ignore nodes which have a certain innertext but you don't know the innertext of the other nodes:

```
<row>
   <column>test</columm>
</row>
<row>
   <column>???</columm>
</row>
```

this is what I tried but didn't work

- row/column[not(.='test')]
- row/column[.!='test']
- row/column[not(text()='test')]
- row/column[text()!='test']
- row[column[text()!='test']]/column

Comment: You have typos in your closing `</column>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the rows where the first `<column>` is not `test`.

```
//row[column[1][. != 'test']]
```

See http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/1ddc1930-ad7f-424c-9800-85df95fe6af3
 (hit "Test!") to run it

Comment: you are right, thx. But what you do if you want the row whose first column doesn't have the innertext 'test'. Every row has 3 columns: //row/column[. != 'test'][1] doesn't work (http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/894aa054-46cb-4b2a-89cd-67105e37b1d3)

Comment: thx alot, i wouldn't have thought of this. Can you also say why [1] has to before [. != 'test)

Comment: @user2211703 The predicate order is significant. See the examples here - http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev